# Handling undelivered emails in webapp

Tags: email

We have a typical business web app that allows our users to send e-mails with offerings to their clients. We set user e-mail in FROM field so the client can reply directly to the user. The problem is that because of SMTP protocol, undelivered e-mail notification is returned to our e-mail address(the address of the account we send e-mails from).

Do you know elegant way to handle this undelivered emails? I mean the easiest way to let the sender know that his mail was not delivered.

Answer (score 19):

First, it's important to understand the difference between the "From:" header (which the  recipient sees in their email client) and the sender address (which is also called the envelope return path, or the argument to the SMTP "MAIL FROM" command). The sender address is where bounce messages go when the email can't be delivered, hence the other name return path.

SMTP doesn't restrict what address you use as the sender address (except that it must by syntactically valid), but whatever SMTP client library you use might, so you'll need to check that out.

Changing the sender address is where you can do clever things to help detect email bounces and report them back to the webapp or sender.  The most common thing you'll see is to encode the *recipient* address in the sender address, e.g. with a sender address like this: sender+recipient=recipientdomain.com@senderdomain.com. The MTA responsible for senderdomain.com needs to know to deliver all emails for sender+foo@senderdomain.com to sender@senderdomain.com -- but that's a fairly common requirement. Then you take the email that is received, and instead of trying to work out from the bounce message in the contents (which could be in any format) who the recipient was, you can get it right from the recipient address.

You can do more complex things as well, like hashing the recipient address so it's not visible directly in the sender address, e.g. sender+e72fab38fb@senderdomain.com.  And you could include some identifier for the email that was sent, in case you're sending multiple emails to the same address and want to know which one bounced.

These tricks are called [Variable Envelope Return Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) or VERP, and are commonly implemented by mailing list software.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 "Headers" that emails have.

1. From.

   - This is what the user sees as the 'originator'
2. Reply-to.

   - This is where an email gets sent if a reply is intented
3. Return-path.

   - This is where an email gets routed in the event that the destination does not exist.

You probably want to be setting the 3rd :)

( Note, some servers don't reply to these lost messages at all, becuase recently spammers have been  putting addresses there that are  not their own, doing a 3rd part bounce attack using the automated reply system to turn email servers into an open relay! )

See Section 4.4 of this document for further details: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html

Answer (score 0):

Exactly which routine are you using to send the Email?
We send emails via raw SMTP using HTTP put_lines and the replies bounce back to the address we nominate in the FROM: field.

See if your SMTP API wrapper has a Reply To: field

Some APIs might not provide that functionality because it increases the possibility of spamming.