# Implementing a mailing list in .NET

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, mailing-list

I am implementing a mailing list using using .NET. As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6383010/125804), I need to send an email where the recipient of the envelope is different from the recipient in the To header. How to achieve this in C#? The SmtpClient and MailMessage classes in System.Net.Mail doens't seem to permit this.

I tried:

```
        message.To.Add("list@example.com");
        message.Headers["Envelope-to"] = "user@example.com";
```

but the mail doesn't get sent to what it is specified in the Envelope-to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adding an address to `Envelope-To` without adding it to `To`**

You can use the [MailMessage.Bcc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx) property. Addresses added there will only appear in the `Envelope-To`, not in the mail's `To`:

```
message.Bcc.Add("user@example.com");
```

---

**Adding an address to `To` without adding it to `Envelope-To`**

Here, I'm quite sure you are out of luck. I've had a look at the System.Net.Mail namespace with ILSpy, and it looks like this is not possible. The `To` header of the mail is created out of the `To` property of the MailMessage (see Message.PrepareHeaders), and the same property is used to fill the `Envelope-To` of the mail (together with the `Cc` and `Bcc` properties, see SmtpClient.Send). Manually setting `Headers["To"]` won't help, since this value is overwritten with the contents of the `To` property (see Message.PrepareHeaders).

So, `list@example.com` *will* get a copy of the message. Depending on the configuration of your SMTP server, this might lead to a mail loop.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Is there any third party smtp client which can achieve this?

Comment: @ChakerNakhli: Unfortunately, I don't know of any. If you don't find one with Google, it might make sense to start a new question on that.

Comment: Yuck. Definitely not what is desired. Use some other library as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/165403/201725), but unfortunately that suggestion is not free. It would be strange that there were no free libraries for this.